# Identify a story or novel accelerated men

Tags: story-identification, pulp, eugenics

I am trying to identify a book or series of books, probably 60's or 70's in date. All dealt with "accelerated men" who were faster and smarter, but only under certain conditions. I can't remember more than that other than that it was pulp style science fiction and I am sure there were a series of books all dealing with the same central character.

Comment: Much more specific info will be required to have any chance of an id.

Comment: Take a look at this [checklist](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for some guidelines on how to write a good story ID question.

Comment: . This sounds like @Hook' by Tully Zetford. Hook is a 'Boosted Man', part of a science experiment.He is the first, and his abilities only kick in when in close proximity to the second run of Boosted Men, who have their abilities permanently.
The Boosted Man 





2.88 avg rating — 16 ratings — published 1974 — 3 editions book 2 
Want to Read 

Rate this book
1 of 5 stars
2 of 5 stars
3 of 5 stars
4 of 5 stars
5 of 5 stars

 
Star City 
by Tully Zetford 





2.67 avg rating

Comment: Sueelleker. I say put it down as an answer. If nothing else, if someone else looks for "accelerated men" or "boosted men", it will come up in search results.

Comment: Tully Zetford was a pen name of Kenneth Bulmer - https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/kenneth-bulmer/ the Amazon reviews confirm (to me) that this is indeed the "Hook" series.

Comment: *"The extra powers conferred on Hook by his Boosting Process were absent at all times except when he came into proximity with another Boosted Man. This was akin to two tuned crystals vibrating when brought together. When he came within the orbit of a Boosted Man - Hook became a Boosted Man himself. It was an experience he feared and loved, that he detested and longed for"*

Comment: thats the series thanks very much

Comment: @sueelleker  Please don't answer in comments.  That "@Hook" should have been an answer in the first place, not a comment.

Comment: Sorry. I usually comment if I'm not 100% sure it's the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

This might be Poul Anderson's novella, 'The Sensitive Man' (1954). Although not a series, his novella 'The UN-man' (and its sequels) I think were closely related.

> "I needn't go into the details of my training. It involved physical exercises, mental practice, some hypnotism, diet and so on. It went considerably beyond the important Synthesis education which is the most advanced thing known to the general public. But its aim—only partially realized as yet—its aim was simply to produce the completely integrated human being."
>
> "There are sound biological reasons why man's mind is so divided and plenty of penalties attached to a case like mine. It'll take me a couple of months to get back in shape after this bout. I'm due for a good old-fashioned nervous breakdown and while it won't last long it won't be much fun while it does last."